# Minimize all but the active of the current application's windows

Tags: keyboard, applescript, window-manager

I switch to, for example, Safari and find the window I want. I can `Command-Option-H` to hide all the other applications, but I *also* want to minimize all the Safari windows except the one I'm using (the front-most one).

Is there a way to do this? Would settle for an AppleScript I can trigger with Keyboard Maestro.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an additional block of _code_ you can try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an AppleScript that *achieves the results* of what you originally explicitly and specifically asked for, before editing the question after it was answered.

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "h" using {command down, option down}
    end tell
    set miniaturized of (windows whose index is not 1) to true
end tell
```

---

Note: The above AppleScript works for me under OS X 10.8.5 and Safari 6.2.8 however I have not tested it on any other version of OS X. That said, I believe it will work fine on other versions of OS X.

---

Update to address the edit of the original question:

I played around a bit with different methods and what I found was, within the ways I tried, most apps worked while some would not. In other words, I didn't find a universal method that worked with all the apps I normally run. So, I'm adding a block of *code* that you can try and see if it can work for you.

Ideally simply hiding all other apps and minimizing the non-active windows of the current app so as to have a smooth appearance in action it what's desired however Finder presented a challenge.  So in this example *code* Finder must minimize all it windows first and bring back what was the frontmost while other apps have a nice cascading effect to minimized non-active windows while leaving the frontmost windows as is.

```
tell application "System Events"
    set frontApp to name of first application process whose frontmost is true
    set windowName to name of first window of application process frontApp
end tell

if not frontApp is "Finder" then
    tell application frontApp
        activate
        tell application "System Events"
            keystroke "h" using {command down, option down}
        end tell
        set miniaturized of (windows whose name is not windowName) to true
    end tell
else
    tell application frontApp
        activate
        tell application "System Events"
            keystroke "h" using {command down, option down}
            keystroke "m" using {command down, option down}
            tell process frontApp to click menu item windowName of menu 1 of menu bar item "Window" of menu bar 1
        end tell
    end tell
end if
```

Comment: Works! However, I was looking for something that'd work for whatever application is front. Adding `set frontApp to name of first application process whose frontmost is true` and then changing "Safari" to frontApp in the first line doesn't seem to work!?

Comment: @Alesh Houdek, In your comment you said, "_I was looking for something that'd work for whatever application is front_" and **that is not at all what you said in your question** as you explicitly and specifically said "_I switch to Safari and find the window I want. I can Command-Option-H to hide all the other applications, but I also want to minimize all the Safari windows except the one I'm using (the front-most one)._" which is exactly what the AppleScript I provided does!

Comment: That is true!!! I guess I was thinking "for example." Very poor question. Still, it's odd that it doesn't work with my slight modification.

Answer (score -1):

This AppleScript will tell the active application to minimize all windows **except** the active (aka frontmost) window.

```
set theFrontApp to (path to frontmost application as Unicode text)
tell application theFrontApp
    set theWindows to the windows whose miniaturized is false
    set theFrontID to the id of the front window
    repeat with theWindow in theWindows
        if the id of theWindow is not theFrontID then set the miniaturized of theWindow to true
    end repeat
end tell
```

Props to @barryels for the nifty [snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25259002/15298091) for theFrontApp.

Comment: This fails if **Finder** is the front most app.