# Build keyboard shortcut for "minimize all windows of current app except the current window"

Tags: automator, shortcut

I'm looking to bind a keyboard shortcut to the action "minimize all windows from the current application except the current window." (The app in question is always Google Chrome.)

(Sort of like `⌘ + ⌥ + h`, which translates to "hide all applications except the current application".)

I've never bound a new shortcut, but I suspect I could figure it out once I have a working AppleScript for the task. I also use Better Touch Tool, in case it is easier to go through that app.

[This](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/119953/minimize-all-windows-except-active) question asks the same thing, but the answers are not bindable to a simple keyboard shortcut as far as I can tell.

[This](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/244071/minimize-all-but-the-active-of-the-current-applications-windows) question asks the same thing (except specifically for Safari), and a user suggests the AppleScript

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "h" using {command down, option down}
    end tell
    set miniaturized of (windows whose index is not 1) to true
end tell
```

When I replace "Safari" with "Google Chrome" in the script, and try to run it from Script Editor, I get the error

```
Script error: Google Chrome got an error: Can’t make miniaturized of every window whose index ≠ 1 into type specifier.
```

Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: As I can see it: after current problem of minimizing is solved this solution creates new problem which must be addressed: 'how to un-minimize other windows of the current app'

Comment: @AivarPaalberg I agree. I personally use the "Session Buddy" Chrome extension which lets me see all open windows and tabs in a list. So that's not a problem for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* will minimize all but the front *window* in **Google Chrome**:

```applescript
tell application "System Events" to ¬
    set miniaturized of windows of application ¬
        "Google Chrome" whose index is not equal to 1 to true
```

Since you already have **BetterTouchTool** and assuming it can run **AppleScript** *code* or an **AppleScript** **.scrpt** *file* with a *keyboard shortcut*, that is probably the easiest way to go to trigger the *code*.

That said, my preferred method for running **AppleScript** *scripts* with a *keyboard shortcut*, is to use a *third-party application* named [**FastScripts**](https://redsweater.com/fastscripts/), however you can also use **Automator** with a **Run AppleScript** *action* as a *Service/Quick Action* and assign it a *keyboard shortcut* in: **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services**

- The *keyboard shortcut* assigned to the *Service/Quick Action* needs to not conflict with a default *keyboard shortcut* for whichever *application* is *frontmost* at the time it's pressed, otherwise there may be unwanted behavior.

---

- <sub>FastScripts can be run as a free app, up to 10 keyboard shortcuts, or upgraded for $24.95 USD to unlock unlimited keyboard shortcuts. I have no affiliation with Red Sweater Software, LLC, other then as a user of FastScripts.</sub>

Comment: I was going to comment that you could more precisely accomplish what the asker requested by replacing `"Google Chrome"` with `(path to frontmost application as text)`—except it turns out that doesn't work in practice. I wonder why...

Comment: @Wowfunhappy The OP explicitly stated "The app in question is always Google Chrome.", so I couldn't be any more precise then I already have!

Comment: Whoops, missed that—I was looking at the question title specifically!